# How can I avoid repetition of array shape declaration for method return value?

Tags: php, phpstan

If, for example, I have a class like this:

```php
class Foo
{
   /**
    * @var array<string, array{name: string, age: int}>
    */
   private array $things;

   /**
    * @return array
    */
   public function getThings(): array
   {
      return $this->things;
   }
}
```

Then phpstan will give me something along the lines of `Method Foo::getThings() return type has no value type specified in iterable type array`.

Of course, I can resolve this by adding the array shape definition to the `@return`, but given that I've already defined this on the property, is there a way to avoid duplication here that I'm missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. PHPStan does not read the method body like that to understand what it returns.

You can use [local type aliases](https://phpstan.org/writing-php-code/phpdoc-types#local-type-aliases) to reduce the duplication:

```php
/** @phpstan-type Things array<string, array{name: string, age: int}> */
class Foo
{
   /**
    * @var Things
    */
   private array $things;

   /**
    * @return Things
    */
   public function getThings(): array
   {
      return $this->things;
   }
}
```

Comment: awesome, thank you! As an aside question/opinion (for better understanding): do you think it would be a reasonable addition to phpstan? Or, could you foresee any problems with handling this sort of thing automatically?

Comment: @MarkG Funny enough, someone asked the same question recently. And the answer is no: https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan/discussions/8137#discussioncomment-3830570

As it's mentioned, maybe Rector already can handle this automatically.